# Complete beginner! Error while running this code that I am unable to identify and fix

Tags: python, directory, unpack

I recently came across this error code while trying to run this file in Visual studio code. Ill link the original github i used with the code that i executed, and the full file of the error code i received.

Original github: https://github.com/MontagueM/DestinyUnpacker?search=1
Was running extractor.py and had gf.py open

Error code:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
    all_packages = os.listdir(path)[::-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 206, in extract_package
    self.get_all_patch_ids()
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 220, in get_all_patch_ids
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Destiny 2/xcurl_license.txt'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:/Program Files (x86)/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/Program Files (x86)/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('C:/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
    all_packages = os.listdir(path)[::-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Extracting files for C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages/w64_venus_01c2_2.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
    unpack_all('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 217, in extract_package
    self.process_blocks(custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 332, in process_blocks
    self.output_files(all_pkg_bin, custom_direc)
    os.mkdir(custom_direc + self.package_directory.split('/w64')[-1][1:-6])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/d2_output_3_0_0_4/venus_01c2'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
    all_packages = os.listdir(path)[::-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Destiny 2\\packages'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Extracting files for C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages/w64_venus_01c2_2.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
    unpack_all('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 217, in extract_package
    self.process_blocks(custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 332, in process_blocks
    self.output_files(all_pkg_bin, custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 367, in output_files
    os.mkdir(custom_direc + self.package_directory.split('/w64')[-1][1:-6])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/d2_output_3_0_0_4/venus_01c2'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Extracting files for C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages/w64_venus_01c2_2.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
    unpack_all('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'C:/d2_output_{3004}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 217, in extract_package
    self.process_blocks(custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 332, in process_blocks
    self.output_files(all_pkg_bin, custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 367, in output_files
    os.mkdir(custom_direc + self.package_directory.split('/w64')[-1][1:-6])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/d2_output_3004/venus_01c2'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Extracting files for C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages/w64_venus_01c2_2.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
    unpack_all('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'C:/d2_output_{3004}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 217, in extract_package
    self.process_blocks(custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 332, in process_blocks
    self.output_files(all_pkg_bin, custom_direc)
    os.mkdir(custom_direc + self.package_directory.split('/w64')[-1][1:-6])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/d2_output_3004/venus_01c2'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
    all_packages = os.listdir(path)[::-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Extracting files for c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages/w64_venus_01c2_2.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
    unpack_all('c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Destiny 2\packages', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 416, in unpack_all
    pkg.extract_package(extract=True, custom_direc=custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 217, in extract_package
    self.process_blocks(custom_direc)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 332, in process_blocks
    self.output_files(all_pkg_bin, custom_direc)
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Admin/Directory/extractor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 421, in <module>
    unpack_all('I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/', custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Directory\extractor.py", line 410, in unpack_all
    all_packages = os.listdir(path)[::-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/'
```

I tried executing it, and I expected it to unpack the .pkg files and load them into a seperate folder or at least dump the output somewhere but it did not happen. Im a complete beginner so I couldnt do much in the realm of troubleshooting no matter how hard i tried

Comment: Have you verified that the directories it cannot find, are actually there?

Comment: They are not there, I tried replacing them with the correct directories that actually led to pkg files but that seemed to tear everything apart.

Comment: Well I haven't looked at the code, but for the error description it's pretty straight forward. It cannot find the specified directories and that's why it crashes. There's one error saying invalid directory name and that's because the string ends with a file, which is not a directory. I see Musabbir has answered it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `extractor.py` file at the 419-422 line where you're calling the `unpack_all` function, fix the directory-path for where **Destiny 2/packages** is located in your system. Also fix the output `custom_direc=f'I:/d2_output_{version}/')` here based on your system.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    version = '3_0_0_4'
    unpack_all('according_to_your_system/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Destiny 2/packages/',
               custom_direc=f'according_to_your_system/d2_output_{version}/')
```

##### Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the advice! i tried doing this to troubleshoot, but was returned with this error code. the only thing that happened is in my output folder one folder was generated for one of the pkg files to dump into but the actual data did not dump into the file. https://pastebin.com/gSTbAT6u

Comment: This is most likely caused by using a 32-bit version of python. The Oodle DLL that is loaded to perform the file decompression requires a 64bit process. To resolve this issue, install the 64-bit version of python 3.

Comment: thanks again for the response, i spent a bit of time making sure everything was updated to 64 bit and the in the correct parameters you told me, unfortunately i am being hit with more issues! here is the error code i was hit with this time https://pastebin.com/vCnvQrwJ

Comment: just making sure, you've already done this step right? "Put oodle dll in same directory. The oodle dll is from Destiny 2 directory"